# Time out with Synchronous NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I am writing an application that uses Synchronous NSURLConnection(s) and am finding that my application hangs if the url entered is incorrect. I tried to set a time out of .5 seconds but it does not seem to take. I read somewhere that it is not possible to set a time out on a Synchronous request (and yes it is very important to the application that the request remains synchronous) but am not sure if this is true. Does anybody know how to set a timeout on a synchronous NSURLConnection or how to time out a given command?

Comment: I need to see your code because it works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiate and work with an NSURLConnection yourself. If you really can't get away from synchronous (smells like bad design to me), run the runloop – preferably in a private mode – while the connection is going to approximate the sync behaviour.